# Redirect url get variables after rewriting htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My original url was this:

```
wwww.domain.com/car-details.php?merk=BMW&model=X5&titel=sale&car_id=3
```

I have Rewrite it into this:

```
wwww.domain.com/BMW/X5/sale/3
```

By putting this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)?$ /car-details.php?merk=$1&model=$2&titel=$3&car_id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

When i put in Url **wwww.domain.com/car-details.php?merk=BMW&model=X5&titel=sale&car_id=3** it still works. I want that url to be redirected to **wwww.domain.com/BMW/X5/sale/3**

I have tried to put the [R] flag in my htaccess RewriteRule but then I'm getting the opposite results.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good decision to do what you want.
But you will face a loop problem.

You can avoid it by using this code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/car-details\.php\?merk=([^&]+)&model=([^&]+)&titel=([^&]+)&car_id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /car-details.php?merk=$1&model=$2&titel=$3&car_id=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this after using the code:


www.domain.com////?merk=BMW&model=6-Serie&titel=BMW-3-serie-in-goede-staat!&car_id=1    And i'm getting my index.php page

Comment: I made a mistake in my code, sorry. I edited my answer, could you try again with the new code ? This should work now...